# How to make parameter type-safe for method that uses Sequelize in TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I'm working with sequelize-typescript in a NestJS project and I have service classes that use sequelize models to run CRUD operations. This is an example:

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from "@nestjs/common"
import { Platform } from "./platform.model"
import { Game } from "../game/game.model"
import { QueryOptionsDto } from "./dto/queryOptions.dto"
import { FindOptions } from "sequelize/types"
import { PLATFORMS_REPOSITORY } from "src/core/constants"

@Injectable()
export class PlatformService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORMS_REPOSITORY) private platformRepository: typeof Platform,
  ) {}

  // the payload parameter is the problem here
  public async addPlatform(payload) {
    try {
      const platform = await this.platformRepository.create(payload)
      return platform
    } catch (err) {
      return Promise.reject(err)
    }
  }
}
```

But I can't assign any type to the `payload` parameter. Naturally, I want to make this type-safe, but TypeScript seems to want the type of the object passed to `.create()` to be the same type as the corresponding model and have all the same properties and methods. This is the error I get if I try to give it an object type with the properties it should have (`{ name: string, year: number }`):

```
Argument of type '{ name: string; year: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Platform'.
  Type '{ name: string; year: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Platform': games, $add, $set, $get, and 33 more.
```

The only solution is to just leave the type as inferred `any` but this obviously defeats the purpose of using TypeScript.

Any suggestions?